# NSOperation, start vs main

Tags: nsoperation, nsoperationqueue

According to Apple document on NSOperation, we have to override `main` method for non-concurrent operations and `start` method for concurrent operations. But why?

Answer (score 31):

First, keep in mind that "concurrent" and "non-concurrent" have somewhat specialized meanings in `NSOperation` that tend to confuse people (and are used synonymously with "asynchronous/synchronous"). "Concurrent" means "the operation will manage its own concurrency and state." "Non-concurrent" means "the operation expects something else, usually a queue, to manage its concurrency, and wants default state handling."

`start` does all the default state handling. Part of that is that it sets `isExecuting`, then calls `main` and when `main` returns, it clears `isExecuting` and sets `isFinished`. Since you're handling your own state, you don't want that (you don't want exiting `main` to finish the operation). So you need to implement your own `start` and not call `super`. Now, you could still have a `main` method if you wanted, but since you're already overriding `start` (and that's the thing the calls `main`), most people just put all the code in `start`.

As a general rule, don't use concurrent operations. They are seldom what you mean. They *definitely* don't mean "things that run in the background." Both kinds of operations can run in the background (and neither *has* to run in the background). The question is whether you want default system behavior (non-concurrent), or whether you want to handle everything yourself (concurrent).

If your idea of handling it yourself is "spin up an `NSThread`," you're almost certainly doing it wrong (unless you're doing this to interface with a C/C++ library that requires it). If it's creating a queue, you're probably doing it wrong (NSOperation has all kinds of features to avoid this). If it's almost anything that looks like "manually handling doing things in the background," you're probably doing it wrong. The default (non-concurrent) behavior is almost certainly better than what you're going to do.

Where concurrent operations can be helpful is in cases that the API you're using already handles concurrency for you. A non-concurrent operation ends when `main` returns. So what if your operation wraps an async thing like `NSURLConnection`? One way to handle that is to use a dispatch group and then call `dispatch_wait` at the end of your `main` so it doesn't return until everything's done. That's ok. I do it all the time. But it blocks a thread that wouldn't otherwise be blocked, which wastes some resources and in some elaborate corner cases could lead to deadlock (*really* elaborate. Apple claims it's possible and they've seen it, but I've never been able to get it to happen even on purpose).

So another way you could do it is to define yourself as a concurrent operation, and set `isFinished` by hand in your `NSURLConnection` delegate methods. Similar situations happen if you're wrapping other async interfaces like Dispatch I/O, and concurrent operations can be more efficient for that.

(In theory, concurrent operations can also be useful when you want to run an operation without using a queue. I can kind of imagine some very convoluted cases where this makes sense, but it's a stretch, and if you're in that boat, I assume you know what you're doing.)

But if you have any question at all, just use the default non-conurrent behavior. You can almost always get the behavior you want that way with little hassle (especially if you use a dispatch group), and then you don't have to wrap your brain around the somewhat confusing explanation of "concurrent" in the docs.

Answer (score 0):

I would assume that concurrent vs. non-concurrent is not just a flag somewhere but a very substantial difference. By having two different methods, it is made absolutely sure that you don't use a concurrent operation where you should use a non-concurrent one or vice versa.

If you get it wrong, your code will absolutely not work because of this design. That's what you want, because you immediately fix it. If there was one method only, then using concurrent instead of non-concurrent would lead to very subtle errors that might be very hard to find. And non-concurrent instead of concurrent will lead to performance problems that you also might miss.

Comment: I think after main finishes it sets 'isFinished' true. It may be one of the reasons.

Comment: This answer seems to assume that "concurrent" means "runs in the background" or something similar. This isn't what "concurrent" means in NSOperation. Concurrent and non-concurrent operations can both run in the background (and so have the "subtle errors" you mention due to multi-threading violations). If run without a queue, either can be completely synchronous. If run with a queue (since 10.6) both will be run on a background thread. The default `start` calls `main`. Concurrent operations must override `start` (the default does non-concurrent behavior). That's the source of the difference.